# Submit facebook application for review

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-apps

I created an fb application which uses the following permissions: manage_pages,publish_pages, and read_insights.
The main purpose of the application is to give to the authenticated user  reports and statics about the popularity of his own fb page.

I noticed that I can't use those permissions until I submit the app for review.
In the facebook developer account, I noticed that for each of the above permissions I have to complete some notes:
1. How a person logs in with Facebook
2. How a person sees the permission used in your app.
Also they want me to upload a video to show them that I use the permission correctly.

**The problem is that I'm not sure what should  the video contain in order to clarify the point 1 and 2.**

Right now my application is only doing the authentication phase (signup), and in the next release we are going to create and display analytics for each user who joined the platform.

I would be grateful, If you could give me some suggestions regarding what facebook would like to know in order to approve the permissions.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your App needs to be working before you can send it in for review. Meaning, you need to have at least a working prototype. For development, you do not need to go through the review process, every permission works for everyone with a role in the App without review.

In other words, you can´t go through review with permissions you don´t even use right now.

Comment: Is this the same situation for Instagram ?

Comment: they have a sandbox mode and a review process, i guess so.